# Sending request using WebClient by HTTPS - POST date doubles

Tags: c#, post, https, webclient

This code

```
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            string address = "https://www.any.com/name.htm";
            byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("login=123");
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "ru-RU";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate";
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            webClient.UploadData(address, postData);
        }
```

produces this request (postData doubles):

```
POST /name.htm HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: ru-RU
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Host: [url]www.any.com[/url]
Content-Length: 9
Connection: Keep-Alive

login=123login=123
```

If I change

```
string address = "https://www.any.com/name.htm"
```

to

```
string address = "http://www.any.com/name.htm"
```

then data don't doubles.

**How avoid data doubling when send request by HTTPS ?**

Comment: I just ran this through a test using Fiddler2 and it did not duplicate data. Sounds like the issue lies someplace else.

Comment: I saw request body from HttpAnalizer6. May be this is bug of HttpAnalizer...

Comment: It's possible. You can try Fiddler2 and see what the result is for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It is bug of HttpAnalizer.

Many thanks to Hardrada.

Comment: How about @Hardrada would post the answer and get the reputation?

Comment: answers and comments are not the same. a +1 for a comment which guided  the OP to his solution is not out of context.